# Georeferencing an image in C# with GDAL

Tags: c#, gdal, .net, geotiff-tiff

I want to upload a jpeg or some raster image into a C# form and then on entering the latitude and longitudes I need to be able to create an GEOTIFF file of the same image. How can this be done in C#.NET?

you had asked me to use GDAL libraries i did add references, 
i'm using Visual studio 2010, i have included library files, 
i have computed llx lly lux luy also, but how to tag it to an image, is there any inbuilt function or anything?

this is the code i have used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OSGeo.GDAL;
using OSGeo.OGR;
using OSGeo.OSR;

namespace geo_tagging
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int orx = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int ory = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int ctrx, ctry, lux, luy, llx, lly, bufx, bufy;
            bufx = orx / 108000;
            bufy = ory / 108000;
            ctrx = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            ctry = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            lux = ctrx - bufx;
            luy = ctry - bufy;
            llx = ctrx + bufx;
            lly = ctry + bufy;

            Gdal.GCPsToGeoTransform(
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();


            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {                     
            PictureBox PictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
            string Chosen_File = "";
            Chosen_File = dlg.FileName;
            textBox1.Text = dlg.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);
            int X = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int Y = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
            label2.Text = X.ToString();
            label4.Text = Y.ToString();

            }

            dlg.Dispose();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text="";
            textBox2.Text="";
            textBox3.Text="";
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

        }

       private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();


            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PictureBox PictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
                string Chosen_File = "";
                Chosen_File = dlg.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = dlg.FileName;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);
                int X = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
                int Y = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
                label2.Text = X.ToString();
                label4.Text = Y.ToString();

            }

            dlg.Dispose();
        }



       private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           textBox1.Text = "";
       }

        }
 }
```

---

**never mind got it guys, we need to use a exe file to call it as a process and pass arguments into it!**

thanks for the help

Comment: I've fixed up your code's formatting but there are bits missing that you might need to fix before someone can answer the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot

actually this shows the way i'm calculating the latitude and longitude of corners based on the center coordinates given

so all i want is a way to generate the geoTiff file by entering the latitude values using any function or library in C# form application Visual Studio 2010,
just need help on function.

this code is running fine for me but

Answer (score 1):

does the code at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702062214/http://www.gdal.org:80/warptut.html) give you any clues? I don't speak C# so I can't tell if it will help or not.

Comment: thanks for the effort cause that is in C++ i want C# so yea..!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to continue would be to make a call to gdalwarp. http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html
Use the -te option to specify your extent:

```
-te xmin ymin xmax ymax:

set georeferenced extents of output file to be created
```

Comment: No like in the Visual Studio C#, do we have any built in function?
from where do i call the GDALWRAP